# Unit Testing MatDialog

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

Im creating a unit test for my confirmation modal that uses MatDialog. my first test is a basic test that the component should be created. here is my code for the spec file.

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { PocitConfirmationModalComponent } from './confirmation-modal.component';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { PortalModule } from '@angular/cdk/portal';
import { MaterialModule } from 'src/app/core/material/material.module';
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';


class MatDialogRefStub {
    close(param: string) {}
}

describe('PocitConfirmationModalComponent', () => {
  let component: PocitConfirmationModalComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<PocitConfirmationModalComponent>;


  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        MaterialModule,
        PortalModule
       ],
      declarations: [PocitConfirmationModalComponent],
      providers: [
          { provide: MatDialogRef, useClass: MatDialogRefStub },
          { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {} },
      ]
    }).overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, {
        set: {
          entryComponents: [ PocitConfirmationModalComponent ],
        }
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PocitConfirmationModalComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

this is the component file that I want to test.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';
import { ComponentPortal } from '@angular/cdk/portal';

@Component({
  selector: 'pocit-confirmation-modal',
  templateUrl: './confirmation-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./confirmation-modal.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class PocitConfirmationModalComponent implements OnInit {

  portal: ComponentPortal<any>;

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<PocitConfirmationModalComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
  ) {
    this.portal = new ComponentPortal(this.data.component);
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  action(type: string) {
    this.dialogRef.close(type);
  }

}
```

after all of these I got this error after running the test.

```
Error: No component factory found for undefined. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

I already added it to entryComponents but still got this error.

Comment: You added it to the entryComponents of BrowserDynamicTestingModule, not your actual test module. Try moving `entryComponents: [ PocitConfirmationModalComponent ]` to be right after you declare the providers in the TestBed configuration.

Comment: @codequiet unfortunately we can't declare entryComponents in the TestBed configuration

Comment: Ah my bad, I was thinking of something else. As far as I know, you shouldn't need to declare entryComponents just for a unit test. It's strange, I copied your code and got it to run without any errors. I was also able to successfully run it with a simplified TestBed configuration (no imports or overriding of modules). The only significant difference should be the HTML that I substituted in for yours. I'd suggest stripping both your component code and test configuration down until the test passes and then re-adding pieces to narrow down/confirm the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //your public data:any model, eg:
const model: any = {
    ActionButton: 'Delete',
    SupportingText: 'Are you sure?',
  };
```

then in providers:

```
providers: [
        {              
          provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA,
          useValue: model
        }
      ]
```